# Strange behavior when converting from a `.json` file that contains an array

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have the following `JSON` file (it's a `bundleconfig.json` file from a VS project):

```
[
    {
        "outputFileName": "Scripts/a.js",
        "inputFiles": [ "Scripts/b.js", "Scripts/c.js" ]
    },
    ...
]
```

and I'm parsing it like so:

```
$json = Get-Content $filePath -Encoding UTF8 | `
    Out-String | `
    ConvertFrom-Json
```

I expected the result `$json` to be an `Array` but it seems that it's not. When I try to see the contents of the array:

```
$json | ForEach-Object { $_ }
```

nothing is printed out (**correction**: It prints empty lines). So, I though that `$json` isn't actually an array and tried to find out its type:

```
$json.GetType()
$json | ForEach-Object { $_ }
```

And here is the strange part. `$json.GetType()` prints out `System.Array` (among other things) and now the `ForEach-Object` works as initially expected!

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
8

outputFileName : Scripts/a.js
inputFiles     : {Scripts/b.js,Scripts/c.js}
```

So, my code only works if the `$json.GetType()` command is present, otherwise it simply doesn't.

I could simply leave the `$json.GetType()` command and get done with it, but I have to know the reason behind this behavior.

Any thoughts?

---

**UPDATE**:

1. It's `PSVersion: 5.0.10586.122`
2. Both files are `UTF-8`
3. This code is part of a [psake](https://github.com/psake/psake) build script, maybe this has something to with it?
4. The file doesn't seem to be the culprit, I tested with a dummy file I made on the fly and the behavior is the same.
5. I can't even reproduce it myself outside the build script. I made a repro folder with the `.json` and those few lines of code (without the `$json.GetType()` command), and it works as expected.

Comment: I cannot reproduce.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce as well... what version of `PowerShell` does this specficially relate to (`$PSVersionTable` should provide this as `PSVersion`)

Comment: Does it print nothing or empty lines? Are you outputting anything else from you script?

Comment: Could you post the actual full json (values obfuscated if needed)?

Comment: Please see my update at the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: Does your input array have only a single item? Powershell "kindly" changes one-object arrays into just the contained object on the pipeline. I was about to make a comment about that, but then kittens started dying, so I stopped.

Comment: Cannot repro in psake. It may be a formatting issue in a complex psake script with various types of output. I have seen some similar effects in Invoke-Build. Try to add `Out-String`, i.e. `$json | ForEach-Object { $_ } | Out-String`